# setting value in a slice of a pandas df raises SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I am following instructions specified [indexing-view-versus-copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) by doing the following:

```
df.loc[:,('ratio')][np.isinf(df.loc[:,('ratio')])] =np.nan
```

But I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning. Essentially I want to set any `inf` values to `np.nan` in situations where I had a divide by zero.

```
<string>:265: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you are doing is [`chained indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing): You are first selecting columns, and then selecting rows from the returned dataframe. `.loc` allows you to select them simultaneously. It accepts a boolean array too, so you can do:

```
df.loc[np.isinf(df['ratio']), 'ratio'] = np.nan
```